# DOS error: "was unexpected at this time."?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

My Windows 7 system path looks something like this:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;....
```

I am trying to set a new user variable based on whether its defined or not already:

```
IF NOT DEFINED DEFAULTP (
  echo Setting DEFAULTP to backup the system PATH
  SETX DEFAULTP=%PATH%
)
```

When I try to do this, I get an error that looks like this:

```
\NVIDIA was unexpected at this time.
```

Can anyone guess why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF NOT DEFINED DEFAULTP (
  echo Setting DEFAULTP to backup the system PATH
  SETX DEFAULTP "%PATH%"
)
```

**Edit:** Running `setx /?` gives these examples:

> Examples:
>        SETX MACHINE COMPAQ
>        SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M
>        **SETX MYPATH "%PATH%"**  
>        SETX MYPATH ~PATH~

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  I guess I was assuming it worked like the "SET" command.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue because there are braces in PATH and it got conflicted with the braces of the IF statement.

the solution is just try to remove braces from IF

```
@rem below will pass
SET PATH_1=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation;%PATH_1%
if "%1" == "1"  set PATH_1=%NEW_PATH%;%PATH_1%

@rem below will fail
SET PATH_1=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation;%PATH_1%
if "%1" == "1" ( set PATH_1=%NEW_PATH%;%PATH_1% )

echo final PATH_1=%PATH_1%
echo over
```

My original demo code that has the error:
(for convenience just rename PATH to PATH_1 )

```
@setlocal
@echo off

set PATH_1=C:\windows
SET NEW_PATH=PATH\TO\SOME_WHRER
SET PATH_1=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation;%PATH_1%

if "%1" == "1" ( 
set PATH_1=%NEW_PATH%;%PATH_1%
)

echo final PATH_1=%PATH_1%

exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you work with a variable containing parentheses inside a code block (the if function in your case). You can indeed circumvent this by adding quotes around your variable (as RonK advises) or by removing the parentheses of the if function (as Michael Hou advises), but the easiest and most secure way is to change `%PATH%` into `!PATH!` inside the code block.

```
IF NOT DEFINED DEFAULTP (
  echo Setting DEFAULTP to backup the system PATH
  SETX DEFAULTP=!PATH!
)
```